# How goes gitHub restrict access only with sshKey?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I'm wandering how does gitHub restrict repo access only by using sshKey.
Everybody is connecting using 'git' user... but the access is restricted only to YOUR repository.

So how is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub is exploiting a feature of OpenSSH.  See the section "AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT" in the sshd(8) man page.  It says that each line in the `authorized_keys` file consists of the following:

```
<options> <keytype> <base64-encoded key> <comment>
```

One of the supported options is `command`:

> - **`command="command"`**  Specifies that the `command` is executed whenever this key is used for authentication.  The command supplied by the user (if any) is ignored.

Thus, GitHub can do stuff like this in their `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file:

```
command="foo -u user1" <user1's key stuff here>
command="foo -u user2" <user2's key stuff here>
```

Now whenever `user1` logs in, the server runs `foo -u user1`.  Thus, the `foo` script knows that `user1` logged in, not some other user.

Comment: and the "foo script" handles the following repository access? Is there an example how to do that part? Thanks!